# Compare arrays and discard empty values?

Tags: php

I have two arrays, I want to return an array which contains only the keys that are in my template:

```
$protected template = ['name' => 'john', 'age'=> 10];

public function merge($params){

    $arr = array_intersect_key($params, $this->template);

}
```

The above works, but I would also like to filter out keys where the value is empty.

So if I pass in:

```
[name => 'jeff', age => '']
```

It would just filter out an array of:

```
[name => 'jeff']
```

Is there a way to do this or would it be best to just loop through the array and do an empty check?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array_filter` to remove empty elements.

```
$template = array_filter($template, 'strlen')
```

Comment: This will remove age in this case also  ['name' => 'john', 'age'=> '0'];

Comment: Are you sure? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d90c1c83f0a44668b5240cfd02d826576b838d49

Comment: Yes I am. You need a callback function to handle this

Comment: Please, do not downvote if you have not run the code first... The comment of @jonju is totaly wrong and confusing. Check the link i sent you above. It runs as expected

Comment: I did not down vote. Why is this wrong? **If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.**. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I have pass the `strlen` callback to array_filter. @jonju did not mean you as downvoter but this was a general request. Also check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091